# Accessing Many-to-Many Values Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

```
article = get_object_or_404(Article,slug=slug)
categories = article.category.all()
```

Using `render_to_response()` , how can I use the categories in the view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the article in the template, you can do the following:

```
# In your view
return render_to_response('page.html', {'article': article})

# In your template
{% for category in article.category.all %}
    {{ category.attribute }}
{% endfor %}

# Or, if you already have the categories
return render_to_response('page.html', {'categories': categories})
{% for category in categories %}
    {{ category.attribute }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually tried to iterate over the object, but it was saying that the object is not iterable. now its working.. any guess where I could have gone wrong ?

Comment: You didn't post your code, but most probably you did `{% for category in article.category %}` -- without the `.all`.